# How to allow only valid values in a combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox, selection

in C# with DotNet 4 i have a form with a combobox which is filled with values when starting the program.
Now user can dropdown and select one of the values.
But: It is also possible to write something new into the combobox-field.

Question: What can i do that it is NOT possible to write something which is not part of the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To make the text portion of a ComboBox non-editable, set the DropDownStyle property to "DropDownList".

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by simply assigning a property to combobox `.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`. but, this property do not allow to edit text. means you have to select item either by mouse or by up/down arrow key. You cannot filter result by selecting this property. if you wish to filter result but don't allow to accept invalid value then you can do this by writing some code in cmb_Validating event

```
private void cmb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmb.SelectedValue == null && cmb.Text != string.Empty)
        e.Cancel=true;
}
```

Comment: When i insert an invalid text to the combobox then nothing happens?
The breakpoint of the new event is stopping at e.cancel = true, but what then?

Comment: Validating event will occur when control focus getting changed. So, application will not allow you to focus another control without assigning a valid value. So, here you have to assign valid value otherwise application will not allow you to do anything in form.